# Where is the 'Viewport Color' node in Animation Nodes 2.1.4?

Tags: animation, node-editor, color

I cannot seem to find the viewport color node in AN 2.1.4. Eventhough the documentation still mentions it..

https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/material/viewport_color.html

Comment: Viewport Node is available for Animation nodes (in blender 2.79) in the search menu. To find, press Ctrl+A then search for "Viewport Color"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should have mentioned that I'm using 2.8.